# Wordpress - Problema al subir imagenes (tengo permisos)

Tags: wordpress, apache

Tengo una pagina wordpress recien instalada. Sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas para subir imagenes.
Cuando quiero subirla, me dice:
El archivo subido no se ha podido mover a wp-content/uploads.

Sin embargo, tengo permisos 755 sobre wp-content, y sobre uploads.
Además, me fije que el usuario que corría el php pudiera escribir sobre la carpeta (entré por ftp con el mismo usuario).

No tengo idea de que pueda ser... Algo que puede estar molestando, es el echo de que es un servidor compartido. Usa suexec para manejar los permisos (pude darme cuenta por que tengo una carpeta llamada cgi-bin en mi public_html).

Alguna idea de como puedo arreglarlo? He leido una cantidad de sitios, y nada me ha dado resultado. Creo que puede ser por el suexec, aunque no entiendo al 100% como funciona.

Comment: Intenta ponernos una captura del directorio de WP abierto con ls -la para ver que permisos tienen y a que usuario y grupo pertenecen las carpetas.  Puede que a pesar de tener bien los permisos la carpeta no pertenezca a/al usuario o grupo del servidor apache, ocurre muy a menudo.

Comment: También puede ser que el hosting tenga activado el _safe mode_ Si está activo mira a ver si te permite cambiarlo, sino tendrás que pedirle al hosting que lo haga por ti

Comment: Aunque por lo que leo por ahí a partir de PHP 5.4 se ha eliminado, si ese es el problema estarias usando una version de PHP demasiado antigua

Comment: El usuario que ejecuta el servidor no debería ser el mismo con el que accedes por FTP ni el mismo con el que accedes al sistema. Trata de verificar los permisos que tiene el usuario que corre el servidor sobre la carpeta y muéstranos los logs de Apache

Comment: perdón. Recien leo todo esto. Es que no tengo acceso por ssh, tengo un cpanel y acceso ftp :/

Comment: Algunos hostings permiten acceder a esas configuraciones desde el gestor. Mira a ver si tienes en tu cpanel una opción que se llame PHP settings, PHP configuration o algo parecidido, si lo tienes busca safe mode

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo tenia el mismo problema. Lo solucione cambiando los permisos a **`777`**. No es lo mejor pero una vez que termine lo que necesitaba hacer volveré los permisos al estado original e intentare resolver el problema de fondo.

Answer (score 0):

En mi Caso fue... desactivar el PHP-FPM y me jodio todos los permisos.... puede que tu hosting server haya instalado PHP-FPM o lo haya desactivado.

Mi Solución, volver a Activarlo y añadir en el htaccess:

```
    # php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
    # Configure el paquete “ea-php73” como el lenguaje de programación predeterminado “PHP”.
    <IfModule mime_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
    </IfModule>
    # php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Segun la Version de PHP que tengas debes variar:

```
    php54 .php .php7 .phtml
    php55 .php .php7 .phtml
    php56 .php .php7 .phtml
    php71 .php .php7 .phtml
    php72 .php .php7 .phtml
```

Answer (score -1):

Dale permiso 777 y accede desde filezila o desde un gestor de archivos ftp que te guste.

Creo que [este artículo](http://2surge.com/how-to-fix-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-error-message/) en inglés podría resolver tu duda, pues también habla de suexec y de lo demás.

Comment: No lo dice pero se supone que los querrá subir desde el gestor de archivos de WP, no desde FTP. Por otra parte darle 777 no es una buena práctica.

Comment: Miré en un lugar que tenían el mismo problema y lo resolvieron poniendo 777. Estoy de acuerdo contigo @JoseFG que no es lo mejor.

Comment: No es que no sea lo mejor, es que es abrir las puertas de par en par, que funcione no quiere decir que sea lo correcto

Comment: Colocando 777 a los permisos, me deja subir archivos, pero luego no me deja colocarlas. Solo me deja colocarlas cuando son galerias (mas de una imagen)

Comment: Revisar [answer]. Principalmente lo relacionado a enlaces.